# How to logically iterate through records using DataReader and then do something at each iteration

Tags: asp.net, dataset, datareader

Please bear with me as I'm rather new to this.

I'm trying to iterate through a recordset using DataReader object, and do something at each iteration, but it doesn't seem to be getting passed the first record. I essentially want to look at each record and then assign a specific image to a specified location based on the data in a column in the recordset.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and using OleDataReader to read Access table. I've got the command object working properly, just can't seem to get passed the first record.

this is the method definition in my class

```
//Giving string variable names to the virtual paths of the images
private string whitePallet = "~/images/White.jpg";
private string redPallet = "~/images/Red.jpg";
private string bluePallet = "~/images/Blue.jpg";
private string blackPallet = "~/images/Black.jpg";
private string greenPallet = "~/images/Green.jpg";

private string racetrack = "~/images/Racetrack.jpeg";
public string Racetrack { get => racetrack; set => racetrack = value; }



public string OpenConnection(string connectString, String selectString)
{
  using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectString))
  {
   cn.Open();  //Open the connection.
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectString, cn); 
   OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string pallet;

                if (reader["Status"].ToString() == "Blocked Location")
                {
                    pallet = blackPallet;
                    return pallet;
                }


                if (reader["Status"].ToString() == "AP Purge")
                {
                    pallet = redPallet;
                    return pallet;
                }


                if (reader["Status"].ToString() == "Open")
                {
                    pallet = whitePallet;
                    return pallet;
                }


                if (reader["Status"].ToString() == "Order Complete")
                {
                    pallet = greenPallet;
                    return pallet;
                }


                if (reader["Status"].ToString() == "Pallet Full")
                {
                    pallet = bluePallet;
                    return pallet;
                }

            }



            //Close the reader and the related connection.
            reader.Close();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

---

this is the instantiation of the class/method
'''

```
 Definitions defs = new Definitions();


 Image imgRacetrack = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(defs.Racetrack));

 //Creating image panel to draw upon using w/h of racetrack image
 Image img = new Bitmap(imgRacetrack.Width, imgRacetrack.Height);


 using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img))
        {
            //Background image
            gr.DrawImage(imgRacetrack, new Point(0, 0));

            //Defining the points on the left side:
            Point p1 = new Point(125, 50);
            Image imgPallet = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(defs.OpenConnection(connectString,selectString)));
            gr.DrawImage(imgPallet, p1);               

            Point p2 = new Point(125, 100);
            Image imgPallet2 = enter code hereImage.FromFile(Server.MapPath(defs.OpenConnection(connectString, selectString)));
            gr.DrawImage(imgPallet2, p2);
        }
```

I'm expecting to iterate through each record and then place the image with the correct color into the correct position, but it's only giving the results to each point/location based on the very first record only. What's wrong with my logic??

Comment: Please forgive the format of my code. I can't seem to get it right for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You declare pallet `string pallet;` then have several `if` statements in which you `return pallet;`.

First, you want to return a string, but you're doing

```
pallet = blackPallet; // pallet will not be a string.

pallet = "blackPallet"; // pallet will be a string.
```

Second, when you say `return...`, you leave the method; you don't continue after that, you are saying you are done - return this value and stop.

So you need to read the value from each row and store them, then return the collection of values. Then you can loop through the collection and plug in each value as needed.

That's one way. I didn't study what you have in complete detail so there might be a better way. Hope that's enough for now.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Yes I think this should work for me. When I leave the method, and then re-instantiate it - it will execute the cmd object all over again never getting passed the first record. Using your suggestion, wouldn't it make sense if I used a DataSet vs . DataReader?? Also- "blackPallet" as above is a string variable representing a path to an image. Looks like I forgot it in my code above.

Comment: Re the string, i should have realized... but now i see you can skip the assignment and just say `return blackPallet;` or `return greenPallet;`... (assuming that part stays in tact after making changes). Returning a dataset works, or a datatable - `return myDataSet.Tables[0]`, or string[], or List<T>. again, i haven't looked closely at the second part so i'm not sure what makes the most sense.